# Dimming LEDs with MOSFET circuit causes low voltage devices to fail

Tags: mosfet, led, pwm, dimming

I am a rookie with electronics and have an issue that is beyond me. To set the scene: I have a number of custom-made circuit boards, all performing different tasks as a part of some automation I am doing. Each circuit board has its own ESP32 microcontroller that interfaces with whatever circuit is on the board. All the circuit boards are powered via a single 24 V power supply ([Mean Well HLG-600H-24A](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-single-output-led-driver-mix-mode-cv-cc-with-hlg--600h--24a)) and I use a buck converter on each board to step down to 5 V for the microcontroller.

I am still setting it all up but for the most part it all works pretty well... that is, except this one thing. I have one board that switches and dims 24 V LED strips. The board has ten channels that look like this:
[image]

Each channel is controlled by sending a PWM signal to the TLP351 optocoupler. The frequency is 1000 Hz and the resolution is 16 bits. I set the brightness of the light by setting the duty cycle.

Now for the fun part. When I dim my all my lights, say all to 75%, strange things start happening. Low-voltage logic devices (on different boards and microcontrollers but same PSU) stop working. For instance, I have a DS18B20 temperature sensor connected via 5 m of cable and it stops working. I have some rotary encoders (3V3 logic) that jump all over the place when I try to use them.

It appears to stop if I put the duty cycle to 0% or 100%. It also seems to stop if I put the lights at different duty cycles (rotary encoders untested on that one).

How do I stop this happening? Is it something to do with the fast switching of the MOSFETs all at the same frequency? Do I put a power line capacitor in to smooth out the fast on/off from the MOSFET? How do I size it? Different frequency? I really appreciate your wisdom on this one.

Also, I tried reading the voltage using a Pockit meter oscilloscope and this is what I got (I am inexperienced with oscilloscopes)...

When the lights are off:
[image]

When the lights are set to 75%:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does each channel have a 7815, or does one 7815 supply all channels?

Comment: @RussellH yes, each channel has it's own 7815

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your [isolated MOSFET driver](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/461004.pdf) has a rise/fall time of 50ns with 3nF load:

[image]

From the gate charge plot of IRF840 and the driver's maximum output current it should switch in about 30ns. This is adequate for a DC-DC converter, but not for dimming LED, because these high di/dt pulses will make a lot of noise on the power supply and turn all your wires into antennas. In other words you inadvertently made a wideband radio jammer. You should try using an AM radio in the same room, with a bit of luck it could also jam up to the FM band ;)

Regarding EMI problems, rise time is key, ie switching time. A high current signal that switches in 30ns is going to make a mess no matter what the frequency is. Every edge both emits a pulse of electromagnetic waves with a wideband spectrum, and creates voltage drop over the inductance of your supply wiring.

So, if you want to keep your current board:

- Increase the gate resistor R3 to 1kOhms to slow down the switching to a few µs.
- Add low inductance decoupling caps to 24V power rail on the board (MLCC).
- Make sure the layout and wiring do not direct the pulsed LED current into a part of the GND that is also used as voltage reference for something else
- Make sure the wires to the LED strips are twisted not loose.

For the next boards:

- Replace expensive MOSFET driver with a 74HCT chip powered by 5V, it acts as a 3V3 to 5V converter with 4mA output current. For example 74HCT245 will drive 8 MOSFETs. ESP32 has wifi, it is natively isolated from everything, so you do not need isolated MOSFET drivers (especially if you don't use the isolation by connecting ground on both sides together).
- Then use logic level MOSFETs that can be driven with 5V, with gate resistor to set switching time to a few µs. You should have no trouble finding 20m0hm SO-8 dual MOSFETs which are much more suitable than IRF840 (RdsON=0.85 ohms, it's a 800V FET).

If you use DS18B20, please note that delayMicroseconds() does not work on ESP32 (the delay is too long by 1-3µs). So the OneWire library, which uses it for bit-banging, also does not work on ESP32: its read error rate is downright shameful. You can use another OneWire library like [OneWireNg](https://github.com/pstolarz/OneWireNg/blob/master/src/platform/Platform_Delay.cpp) or [this one](https://github.com/peufeu2/ESP32FastMillis).

EDIT: Using 74HCT245 for 2-8 MOSFETs. If you only need two channels you can also use any HCT logic gate, AND, OR, Buffer, whatever. The important thing is that it's HCT since it will read 3V3 levels correctly on the input, and output 5V.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to explain the issue in such detail, I had no idea about any of this - cool but not what I wanted to create . I had someone design the circuit and board for me - he designed it to "reduce noise". The irony. Taking your guidance I have redesign the circuit. Is this what I should be doing [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj7TF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj7TF.png)? I added some decoupling caps also - I did some research and found that 0.1uf and 10uf in parallel was a good starting point/catch all? Thank you for helping me learn.

Comment: Did not know about OneWire either. Thank you, I'll look at those other libraries.

Comment: It looks much better, but your MOSFET is wired the wrong way. I added a schematic to the answer. Yes for capacitors. If your LEDs use a lot of current you could also add an electrolytic cap, maybe 1000µF, value is not critical "as long as it's high enough". If your wires to the supply are very short, then it's not needed. Could the buck module be one of the garbage counterfeit "LM2596" found everywhere on the internet?

Comment: Oh man that is embarrassing. Yes, it's an N-Channel. In my defence it was pre-coffee. I was quickly throwing something together before I had to get out the door and focused on interfacing the chips and threw the voltage nets on in a rush. Good idea on adding a cap to the supply also. I'll see if I can create a new board. Not a LM2596 but no doubt still garbage https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002921104409.html. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Well if it doesn't have electrolytic caps and name brand chip, it can't have garbage electrolytic caps and counterfeit chip!

Answer (score 10):

You're not getting much, if any, benefit from optoisolating the drive signal when both grounds are tied together.

Look carefully at the path the LED currents take back to the power supply and make sure that it's not going back in a path that's tapped off for grounds on the control circuits. If you can separate the below indicated nodes and wire them directly back to the power supply it may help:

[image]

Also the 3 LM7815 ground nodes (tied directly to the MOSFET and U3, not with a separate conductor) **if** it does not do anything else.

As a kind of crude test you can try increasing R3 to something like 4.7K and see if the problem is mitigated. That will slow the switching and may help compensate for bad layout. Don't go much more than that without adjusting R4 upwards.

Also give U3 a bypass capacitor nearby on the +15V side if you don't already have one.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate you helping me learn. I had someone design the board for me, it was beyond my experience so I just followed what they specified. I might try increasing the resistor, else I might even redesign the board and do it properly using @bobflux guidance this is what I am looking at [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj7TF.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj7TF.png). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a circuit that powered high power LEDs with mosfets and looking at the drain side of the mosfet there was significant high frequency oscillation as a result of the lead inductance and the very fast switching time. You don't want to try and slow that down with a larger gate resistor because depending on the power rating of the mosfet you run a risk of it spending time in the linear transition portion of its curve and this can cause device failure due to the Spirito Effect. Instead I put a snubber network from drain to source consisting of a low value resistor and a cap - can't remember the exact values now, I think it might have been 10 ohms and 0.001uF for a 3W LED, you may want to experiment and you need a decent scope with e.g 200MHz bandwidth really for this sort of work.

Comment: Oh, man this problem keeps getting more complicated by the day. I certainly don't have that level of experience. I am assuming there is no simple way to implement a snubber network? I am running 24V COB LED strips from each channel.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there appears ringing (high voltage spikes) of wires  LED strip.It leads to reset of your ESP32. To reduce this ringind - you must connect a snubber RC circuit - 22nF capaitor and 33 Ohm resistor (1Watt) in parallel between drain and ground.It reduces high vootage spikes dramatically.Important: add zener diode (3.6v) to PWM pin of ESP32. If the effect was weak - connect a bidirectional snubber diode ( series P500KE)  36V between drain +24v.

Answer (score 0):

You show a buck converter as U6. Is that a chip or some module you added, etc? I'd expect a buck converter to have 20uF (two 10uF in parallel) on the input and 66uF (three 22uF in parallel) on the output.

Try running all the MCU(s) on a separate 5v4A power supply. By using the separate power supply, you could even avoid connecting the grounds between the high-current noisy 24vdc supply and your 5vdc power. If that helps, either continue using that.

or

It might be worth adding a diode to the buck converter's input between the 24V supply and C3. This will let current flow into the buck converter, but if the LEDs pull the 24Vdc rail down, the diode will prevent the input capacitors from being discharged.

Answer (score 0):

Could the software controlling the LEDs be changed to start and keep the PWM outputs out of phase with each other? The more strips you add, the more the phase would need to adjust. Two strips can be 180 degrees out of phase, and three strips 120 degrees, following the formula 360 / N, where N is the number of strips you are driving. This could smooth out the surges in the power supply.